# Wingpanel crashing with string_contains: assertion 'self != NULL' failed

Tags: settings, wingpanel, crash

since last Friday, my wingpanel (and settings) are crashing. I didn't change OS in any way except some OS updates. I tried several fixes found on stackexchange, reddit and bug reports including:

- Removing all wingpanel indicators, at least those with name starting with wingpanel-indicator.
- Uninstalled elementarytweaks using apt purge
- sudo apt-get remove indicator-synapse
- sudo apt remove switchboard-plug-security-privacy
- removing ~./config
- reinstalling wingpanel using apt remove and apt purge
- Creating new account

The error when running with wingpanel(crash for settings below) --debug flag:

```
** (wingpanel:12939): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-CeZKyHU9bw: Connection refused

(wingpanel:12939): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2045:14: 'min-height' is not a valid property name

(wingpanel:12939): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2046:13: 'min-width' is not a valid property name

(wingpanel:12939): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2051:13: 'min-width' is not a valid property name
[INFO 08:42:03.387099] Application.vala:153: System Panel version: 2.0 .2
[INFO 08:42:03.387168] Application.vala:155: Kernel version: 4.4.0-78-generic
[DEBUG 08:42:03.388244] [Gtk] Connecting to session manager
[DEBUG 08:42:03.395298] Slingshot.vala:85: Activating Slingshot
[DEBUG 08:42:03.395441] IndicatorManager.vala:314: app-launcher registered
[DEBUG 08:42:03.398383] Settings.vala:163: Loading settings from schema 'org.pantheon.desktop.slingshot'
[DEBUG 08:42:03.402265] sql-schema.vala:204: schema_version is 10
[DEBUG 08:42:03.403555] AppSystem.vala:50: Updating Applications menu tree...
[DEBUG 08:42:03.453277] sql-schema.vala:204: schema_version is 10
[06:42:03.498754 Gtk-Warning] Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2045:14: 'min-height' is not a valid property name
[06:42:03.498788 Gtk-Warning] Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2046:13: 'min-width' is not a valid property name
[06:42:03.498811 Gtk-Warning] Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2051:13: 'min-width' is not a valid property name
[06:42:04.164340 Gtk-Critical] gtk_window_resize: assertion 'width > 0' failed
[INFO 08:42:04.171328] DBusService.vala:64: Service registration suceeded
[06:42:04.213923 Warning] [DesktopFileInfo] Unable to get exec for Other
[06:42:04.221050 Warning] [DesktopFileInfo] Unable to create AppInfo
Systemd is not present
[06:42:04.276076 Critical] string_contains: assertion 'self != NULL' failed
[06:42:04.276090 Critical] string_contains: assertion 'self != NULL' failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Just to be sure I included switchboard(settings) crash output because it is similar and started also last Friday.

```
** (switchboard:15800): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-CeZKyHU9bw: Connection refused

(switchboard:15800): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2045:14: 'min-height' is not a valid property name

(switchboard:15800): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2046:13: 'min-width' is not a valid property name

(switchboard:15800): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2051:13: 'min-width' is not a valid property name
[INFO 08:50:10.694749] Application.vala:153: System Settings version: 2.0
[INFO 08:50:10.694791] Application.vala:155: Kernel version: 4.4.0-78-generic
[DEBUG 08:50:10.695613] [Gtk] Connecting to session manager
[DEBUG 08:50:10.698787] DisplayPlug.vala:214: Activating Display plug
[DEBUG 08:50:10.699607] PlugsManager.vala:91: pantheon-display registered
[DEBUG 08:50:10.700833] ColorPlug.vala:95: Activating Color plug
[DEBUG 08:50:10.701130] PlugsManager.vala:91: hardware-gcc-color registered
[DEBUG 08:50:10.701992] SoundPlug.vala:145: Activating Sound plug
[DEBUG 08:50:10.702162] PlugsManager.vala:91: hardware-gcc-sound registered
[DEBUG 08:50:10.702867] WacomPlug.vala:95: Activating Wacom plug
[DEBUG 08:50:10.703019] PlugsManager.vala:91: hardware-gcc-wacom registered
[DEBUG 08:50:10.703802] keyboard.vala:76: Activating Keyboard plug
[DEBUG 08:50:10.703973] PlugsManager.vala:91: hardware-pantheon-keyboard registered
[DEBUG 08:50:10.704607] mouse-touchpad.vala:134: Activating Mouse-Touchpad plug
[DEBUG 08:50:10.704752] PlugsManager.vala:91: pantheon-mouse-touchpad registered
[DEBUG 08:50:10.705405] Plug.vala:404: Activating Power plug
[DEBUG 08:50:10.709302] Battery.vala:69: battery path:/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0 , its a laptop, dbus connected
Systemd is not present
[FATAL 08:50:10.714374] string_contains: assertion 'self != NULL' failed
[FATAL 08:50:10.714465] string_contains: assertion 'self != NULL' failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Running sudo apt remove switchboard-plug-power  did resolve the issue.